# In ST_CoverageSimplify can the OVER() clause be used to reduce memory requirements?

Tags: postgis, land-cover

With a large coverage of polygons in PostGIS, can the `OVER()` clause in `ST_CoverageSimplify()`(1) be used to `PARTITION( by 'x')` the coverage and possibly reduce memory requirements. My attempts to include a `PARTITION BY` have not worked. (why is it a winset?)

For a coverage of 1.7M polygons `ST_CoverageSimplify()` was able to reduce that from approx 2GB to half the size in less than 1/2 hr. Fantastic new tool and credit to the JTS and PostGIS teams.

A larger coverage (80GB 14M features) is not playing ball and I'm seeking ways to make it more digestible and to determine what the bottle necks for the function are. I could break it up on regional boundaries into say 100 parts but that will be a lot of code I think.

```
Version:"POSTGIS=""3.4.1 3.4.1"" [EXTENSION] PGSQL=""160"" GEOS=""3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1"" SFCGAL=""SFCGAL 1.5.0, CGAL 5.6, BOOST 1.78.0"" PROJ=""8.2.1 NETWORK_ENABLED=OFF URL_ENDPOINT=https://cdn.proj.org xxx GDAL=""GDAL 3.7.1, released 2023/07/06"" LIBXML=""2.9.14"" LIBJSON=""0.12"" LIBPROTOBUF=""1.2.1"" WAGYU=""0.5.0 (Internal)"" TOPOLOGY RASTER"
```

---

--- EDIT below ---

Code for testing;

```
WITH coverage(id, grp, geom) AS (VALUES
 (1, 'a', 'POLYGON ((160 150, 110 130, 90 100, 90 70, 60 60, 50 10, 30 30, 40 50, 25 40, 10 60, 30 100, 30 120, 20 170, 60 180, 90 190, 130 180, 130 160, 160 150), (40 160, 50 140, 66 125, 60 100, 80 140, 90 170, 60 160, 40 160))'::geometry),
 (2, 'a', 'POLYGON ((40 160, 60 160, 90 170, 80 140, 60 100, 66 125, 50 140, 40 160))'::geometry),
 (3, 'b', 'POLYGON ((110 130, 160 50, 140 50, 120 33, 90 30, 50 10, 60 60, 90 70, 90 100, 110 130))'::geometry),
 (4, 'c', 'POLYGON ((160 150, 150 120, 160 90, 160 50, 110 130, 160 150))'::geometry) )
SELECT  
id, 
grp, 
-- geom -- for testing
ST_CoverageSimplify(geom, 30, 'false') OVER (PARTITION BY 'grp') AS geom
 FROM coverage;
```

Gives this image [image: simplified internally]

1. https://postgis.net/docs/ST_CoverageSimplify.html

Perhaps this does reduce memory by only working on one set at a time, but as far as I can see, it still treats the small internal triangle at the top as if it were independent of any grouping, i.e. it simplifies it's boundary even though it and the surrounding area belong to grp a.

Comment: Why is using `PARTITION BY` not working?

Comment: If you can find a way to partition into smaller sets of contiguous features, you could use `ST_CoverageSimplify` with `simplifyBoundary = false` to simplify each set separately, while preserving topology between the sets.  That might reduce data size enough that a final full simplify works.

Comment: Using `simplifyBoundary=false`preserves the outer boundaries, but simplifies the inner ones.  That's why the inner small triangle has been simplified.

Comment: Thanks dr_jts - I see that but I was assuming if the function works as a window, it would treat each group which has been partitioned separately as a discrete polygon as well (because I am seeking to understand how the data is handled in memory, so as to reduce processing).

Comment: I would expect that each partition would be processed independently.  But they might be gathered up concurrently - which might still blow memory for your dataset?

Comment: Another idea: don't use `PARTITION BY`, run a separate query for each set (i.e. using a `WHERE` clause to extract only a subset of the data records).

Comment: I hear you re `WHERE` but I expect I have to break this into separate transactions to reduce resource usage, not just separate queries/scripts. Also breaking into separate `writes` will aid in troubleshooting, might reveal if it is actually dodgy geometry.

Comment: *Are* you limited by memory or is the bottleneck CPU or IO?

Comment: memory is the limit - 80GB govt issued table

Answer (score 0):

The `OVER()` function does not provide a pathway to reduce resource requirements. Regardless if the `FALSE` parameter is used in the ST_CoverageSimplify function, all the features in the query will be loaded into memory, setting that parameter will only alleviate simplification of the boundary, which in my use case is a trivial resource requirement.

The transaction in Postgres must be completed before memory is released. Managing resources requires the creation of consecutive transactions. To achieve an unattended run `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;` can be woven through a series of scripts in PGAdmin to start and complete transactions.